# Django ModelForm not displaying all fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to build forms linked to a PostgreSQL database using Django ModelForms. The template is rendering two of the fields(the ones with ManyToMany relationships), but it only gives me an empty box for "title".

This is my forms.py:

Forms.py:

```
class ProgramForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Program
    fields = ['function','task', 'title']
widgets = {
    'function' : forms.Select,
    'task' : forms.Select,
    'title' : forms.Select,
    }
```

This is my Models.py:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    function = models.ManyToManyField(function, related_name='programs')
    task = models.ManyToManyField(Task, related_name='programs')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Task(models.Model):
    tasknum = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    taskname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    task_num_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function, related_name="tasks")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.task_num_name

class Function(models.Model):
    function = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    function_abrev = models.CharField(max_length = 25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.function
```

Views.py:

```
def main(request):
    return render (request, 'assignments/main.html')

def add_program(request):
    form = ProgramForm()
    return render (request, 'assignments/ad_form.html', {"form":form})

def link(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProgramForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse("we maybe getting somewhere") 
    else: 
        return HttpResponse("keep working")
```

I need a couple of things to happen:

1. I need for the "title" to render in the html page as a scroll down(the same way "function" and "task" appear.
2. I need to be able to save the relationships. The models are populated with all the information required with the exception of the relationships. The objective is for a staff member to be able to chose a "function", for that choice to act as a filter for the "task" scroll down(function and task have a OneToMany), and then allow them to choose any programs they want to add to their portfolio.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The Task and Function models have indentation problems - is that a mistake made in writing this question?

Comment: It was a mistake when copying/pasting the code. I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Title field in form**

For this, I don't quite understand how the title field could be a scroll down the same way function and task are. Function and task are drop downs because they are manytomany fields linked to other models, meaning that the user has to pick which other objects in the Functions model and the Tasks model are to be linked. The title field, on the other hand, is just a CharField and so there is no defined set of things for the user to pick from. To allow the user to enter in the title for the Program, you should change the widget for title to Textarea() as such:

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea

class ProgramForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = ['function','task', 'title']
    widgets = {
        'function' : forms.Select,
        'task' : forms.Select,
        'title' : Textarea(),
    }
```

**2. Save the Program from the form**

To save the Program created by the user on staff member, simply add form.save() to your link(request) function:

**views.py**

```
def link(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProgramForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("we maybe getting somewhere") 
        else: 
            return HttpResponse("keep working")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Additionally, OP perhaps should consider changing the widgets or getting rid of the `Meta.widgets` altogether. The default widgets for the fields would almost certainly work better.

Comment: The reason I need a scroll down for the title is because the Program model has about 300 programs and I need the users to select which programs they want. Is there a way of making this work with a scroll down and not by manually typing the programs?

Comment: @dev_2018 to do that you can use the choices argument on the title field to specify a list of titles that the title value should come from. The documentation explains it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: The choices argument seems to be practical if you only have a handful of choices. I have more than 300 programs.

Comment: What you can do is put the list of choices in a separate py file to and then import the list to compartmentalize it. However, if you want to limit them to choosing from a set of 300 titles, no matter what approach you take you will have to list out the titles somewhere. Are the titles programmatically generated?

Comment: I was able to make it work by doing a query from views.py and passing it to the template: 

def function_page(request, Function_id):
    assignments = Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)
   programs = assignments.programs.all()
    context = {
        'assignments': assignments,
        programs' : programs
    }
    return render (request, 'function.html', context)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a query from views.py and pass if to the template.

```
Views.py 

def function_page(request, Function_id):
assignments = Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)
programs = assignments.programs.all()
context = {
   'assignments': assignments,
   'programs' : programs
}
return render (request, 'function.html', context)
```

HTML

```
 {% for program in programs %}
      <option value="{{program.title}}">{{program.title}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
```